# Image not properly displayed in framelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, android-tablelayout

I am Using a imageview under framelayout . I applied a background image in image view but image cannot fully cover the screen. it appears in center. I want to fully cover the Screen ...

How can i achieve it? 
Thanx in advance :-)

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.muhammad.maqalatlayout.jild_copy"
android:background="@color/Green">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/brown_border1"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left|bottom|center_vertical|right"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
```

[My Current output is like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxItR.png)

Comment: Did you try `scaleType="fitXY"`?

Comment: Yes! i tried this but it wont effect the layout!

Comment: Then I guess, your image has a transparent area beyond the border. You need to get rid of that.

Comment: I tried this https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=Psd+frame+images&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=isch&imgil=MutjObiZJkrOAM%253A%253BGf7k52mBQMHVWM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.vectorhq.com%25252Fpsd%25252Fframe-psd-469320&source=iu&pf=m&fir=MutjObiZJkrOAM%253A%252CGf7k52mBQMHVWM%252C_&usg=__f-mNE4NntpLQkB73vev1mEwTxZE%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiQuvvbgarOAhWGcBoKHar_An8QyjcIMg&ei=QWOkV9CVAYbhaar_i_gH#imgrc=MutjObiZJkrOAM%3A   image it also give me the same output. I properly crop the image having no transparent border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your scale isn't working because you are setting the `android:background` property. Try this:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:src="@mipmap/brown_border1"
    ... />
```

Also, preferably put your image in the `/drawable/` folder.

Comment: no effect!  `<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/check_background"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left|bottom|center_vertical|right"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />`

Comment: @Muhammadwajih Can you upload your project on google drive or something so I can try?

Comment: `package com.example.muhammad.maqalatlayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class jild_copy extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jild_copy);
    }
}
`

Comment: @Muhammadwajih listen, instead of copying here, make a zip file of your project and upload on Google Drive.

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/4n4tv6ul46bx168/Maqalatlayout1.rar?dl=0] here is my project!

Comment: @Muhammadwajih tried your project. The image that was in the project dies have a large transparent edge like I mentioned earlier. However, when I dowloaded and tried the image from your link you posted earlier in your comment, everything was as expected on my side. If you have some doubt, try Ctrl+Click on the image name in xml and you shall see a transparent border.

Comment: @Muhammadwajih I just saw the image that was already in your project had borders so I downloaded the image in the link you provided and simply saved it in `drawable/` folder

Comment: Thankyou for ur help :-) Task Done :-)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY" and `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`.
```

Comment: After using this no change appears in the output !

Comment: android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: and set the image as android:src="@mipmap/brown_border1"